# Anything similar to Hibernate in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, hibernate, database-design

I am a Java programmer and was working on a project using Hibernate and Struts for some time.

Now For my new project, I am working on PHP and Mysql (learning PHP).
Is there any technology which is similar to Hibernate for PHP? If yes, can anyone give me the link where I can understand and use it?

Is there a POJO concept in PHP?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In my opinion the best ORM for PHP is [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

You may also wish to check out [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and see which suits your style better.

[PHP ORMs: Doctrine vs. Propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062473/php-orms-doctrine-vs-propel) is a recent SO question  comparing the two. Common PHP frameworks like Symfony let you use either ORM as far as I recall.

As far as POJOs, as far as I know you'd use stdClass for that in PHP. I'm not much with Java  though, so I can't say for sure. Here's an SO Question about that... [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

Answer (score 9):

If you need ORM, you can try [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Answer (score 5):

If you're not stuck on PHP (e.g. you can use any scripting language), **Perl** has both POJO concept (Perl objects) and Hibernate alternatives (including [hibernate Perl port](http://ostatic.com/phibernate); and several [Object-Relational Mapping classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Perl)).

If you're forced into PHP, you can see alist of OR/M for PHP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP)

Answer (score 2):

There is also dmz as a doctrine alternative: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/ which is very simple to setup and made to work with codeigniter.