# is it possible to use hibernate in php yii framework?

Tags: php, hibernate, yii

Currently i'm developing a web application by using php yii framework, is there any option to use hibernate in yii php framwork ?

Comment: You mean this Hibernate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605074/anything-similar-to-hibernate-in-php

Comment: Or like Hibernate Windows

Answer (score 0):

In Yii there is active record ORM concept.Hibernate mainly using for connecting java application and relational mapping of java object to data base. Table columns will mapp to properties of model class.