# How should PHP classes interact with the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

The other day, while developing my PHP project and implementing the `User` class, i started to wonder how this class should interact with the MySQL database the project is using.

Let me start with an example:  let's say I have a `getName()` method, inside the `User` class,  that returns the user's real name. What's the more fitting way to implement that method?

I came up with 2 solutions:

1. I put the DB query inside the `getName()` and only get what I need like this:

   ```
   public function getName() {

       // MySQL query code here
   }
   ```
2. I create a `load()` method inside the `User` class that load all the user data inside the class structure and then the `getName()` is something like this:

   ```
   private $name;

   // Load all user data inside the class' structure
   public function load() {

       $this->name = // MySQL query here
   }

   public function getName() {

       return $this->name;
   }
   ```

I thought, not sure if mistakenly or not, that the first way is more efficient because i only get the data I need, while the second way is more OOP but less efficient.

So, here's the question: what is the better way? Why? Are there better ways?

Comment: Either way, consider storing/caching the results of that so you do not make a query every time you use getName on that object.
Also, consider not wrrying about all that by using a ORM/DBAL Solution like propel or doctrine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062473/php-orms-doctrine-vs-propel

Comment: Also check out Lazy Loading and the Active Record Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

Comment: @AndreschSerj I found your comment very helpful, if you write down the answer I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way, consider storing/caching the results of that so you do not make a query every time you use getName on that object. 
Also, consider not wrrying about all that by using a ORM/DBAL Solution like [propel or doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062473/php-orms-doctrine-vs-propel).

Also check out Lazy Loading and the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Run your query just in time and only run it once (unless you know the value might change), try something like the following:

```
 class User {
   protected $data;

   function getName()
   {
     if (!isset($data['name'])) {
       // if you can load more than just $this->data['name'] in one query
       // you probably should.
       $this->data['name'] = // query here
     }
     return $this->data['name'];
   }

 }
```

Comment: Don't you think the overhead of reading probably 6 fields in one query is worth not doing 6 queries and thus, the load should load all the cols from the table involved?

Comment: @AndreschSerj loading all columns would be best, instead of $this->data['name'], maybe just `$this->data = getQueryResultsAsArra();`

Comment: What i meant exactly :D

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the question being kinda broad (as there are countless patterns), the second way you mentioned is better IMO, and to add to it I would also suggest supplying ID as a parameter which you could then use to build a single query to fetch the user by ID and then manually assign all properties (from the fetched row).